# CAPS lock popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a popover when the CAPS lock key is on during typing password, the code is working fine, the popover is displayed when CAPS is on and is hidden when it is not. But I'm also getting the popover when I click on the password field, even if the caps is not on.

I need some help with this.

```
<input rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="CAPS IS ON" type="password" id="txtPassword" name="password" class="input-xlarge" value="" size="20" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#txtPassword').keypress(function(e) { 
        var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
        if ( s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey ) {
            jQuery('#txtPassword').popover('show');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#txtPassword').popover('hide');
        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: a `keypress` event shouldn't fire on a mouse click. Please show your entire code, possibly with a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

TRY

**UPDATE**

HTML

`Type Here:<br><input type="text" id="textbox"><br>On each keypress I will tell if caps lock is on<br><br> CAPS LOCK: <span id="cap"></spa`n>

JQUERY

```
//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#textbox').keypress(function(e) { 
    var s = String.fromCharCode( e.which );
    if (s.toUpperCase() === s && s.toLowerCase() !== s && !e.shiftKey) {
        $('#cap').removeClass('red').addClass('green').html('ON');
    } else {
        $('#cap').removeClass('green').addClass('red').html('OFF');
    }
});
});//]]> 


css
.red {
  color: red;    
  font-weight:bold;
}
.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight:bold;    
}
```

Comment: this works fine, so does my code,it is the same, my issue here is that i am getting an unnecessary popover onClick

Answer (score 0):

### Update Answer: to detect Capital letter

Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Z52Az/4/

Use this script,

```
$('#txtPassword').keyup(function () {
    var character = $('#txtPassword').val();
    var lastChar = character.substr(character.length - 1);
    if (lastChar == lastChar.toUpperCase()) {
        alert ('You typed capital letter!');
    }
});
```

Comment: CHECK MY UPDATE ANSWER AGAIN.

Comment: you want to detect caps lock on, right?, whether you press shift+small charcter while caps lock is on.

Comment: no when capslock is off...i press "shift+small charcter" it should return capslock is on..

Comment: you want to detect only Capital letter, not CAPS lock is being on.